# How to create range on replaced id?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have id div which contains text then I change its content and replacing with duplicate, but after this action I cannot create range. There is the error:

> Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'surroundContents' on
>   'Range': The container node is a detached character data node; no
>   parent node is available for insertion.

How can I replace innerHTML so that I can get ability to create range?[enter link description here][1]

```js
var dupl = "";
function Selection()
{
        if(dupl == "") { dupl = document.getElementById('content').innerHTML; }
        
        var sel = window.getSelection();
        var anchor = sel.anchorNode;
        var anchoroffset = sel.anchorOffset;
        var focus = sel.focusNode;
        var focusoffset = sel.focusOffset;
            anchoroffset=anchoroffset+3;
            focusoffset= focusoffset +3;

       $("#content").html(dupl); 
       
       var range = document.createRange();
       range.setStart(anchor, anchoroffset); 
       range.setEnd(focus, focusoffset); 
       var newNode = document.createElement("b");
       range.surroundContents(newNode);

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content" onmouseup="Selection()">
<br>Hello fg hfg hfg hfg
<br>World! hfg hfg fg 
<br>
<a href="#">Here is your dream</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you share your try (code), please!

Comment: @Mohamed Abbas, I'd added code.